# Arduino WiFly shield with SPI

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino Uno with the [WiFly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954) [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields). I want to use 5 [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) ports on the Arduino to control motors, but some of the PWM ports are used by the WiFly. Looking into it, I think I need to use the [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) bus, but is this possible with the WiFly shield or how do I go about it?

How am I supposed to wire the motors so that they can work alongside the WiFly?

Can you point to a tutorial (I haven't been able to find one similar enough to my case to understand) or can you give me some pointers? That would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you should try in the [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to get the WiFly module working is a serial link with it. One option is to use a soft serial library. This way you can choose which arduino pins you want to use (only 2 are needed leaving all the others available to control your motors). See [this tutorial](http://cairohackerspace.blogspot.no/2011/05/beginners-guide-to-connecting-and.html) for a complete example.